# Is it possible that $f(g(x))$ has four roots as $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two quadratic expressions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, contest-math

This problem is from a previous year mathematics olympiad.

> Is it possible that $f(g(x))$ has four roots as $1$, $2$, $3$, $4$ if $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two quadratic expressions?

So I tried considering real and non-real cases but couldn’t find anything. It would be great if any one can help me.

It would be a great help for other Olympiad aspirants.

Comment: Can anyone plz address the above problem. I need it for my Olympiad preparation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is heuristic method.

As the goal is to obtain

$$h(x)=\underbrace{(x-1)(x-4)}_{f_1(x)}\underbrace{(x-2)(x-3)}_{f_2(x)}\tag{1}$$

If we remark that

$$\begin{cases}g_1(x)=(x-1)(x-4)=x^2-5x+4\\g_2(x)=(x-2)(x-3)=x^2-5x+6\end{cases}\tag{2}$$

we can write :

$$h(x)=g_1(x)(g_1(x)+2) \ \ \iff \ \ h(x)=f(g_1(x)) \ \ \text{with} \ \  \begin{cases}f(x):=x(x+2)\\g_1(x)=x^2-5x+4\end{cases} \tag{3}$$

which is a second solution.

Please note that this has been made possible because by a "smart" gathering of factors $(x-k)$ in (1) allowing a same first degree term $5x$ in (2) which has been cancelled at the next step.

---

**Edit 1 :** there is fact an infinite number of solutions (obtained by a Computer Algebra System : OK, non available for Olympiads) ; among them,

> $$\begin{cases}f(x):=x^2+(10-2a)x+(a^2-10a+24)\\g(x)=x^2-5x+a\end{cases}$$
>   depending on the real parameter $a$. For example,

- taking $a=4$, we retrieve solution (3) above,
- taking $a=6$ gives back the solution of @Don Thousand.

---

**Edit 2:** A simple - and different - approach is to give the issue a symmetrical aspect.

How ? By replacing $x=1,2,3,4$ by $y=2x-5=-3,-1,1,3,$

in order to have an even polynomial with these roots, i.e.,

$$(y^2-1)(y^2-9)=g(y)(g(y)-8)=f(g(y)) \ \ \text{with} \ \ f(z):=z(z-8).$$

It remains to come back to variable $x$ by replacing $y$ by $2x-5$.

Comment: This is quite a rigorous proof. But can u please try generalise the equations getting certain relation between both the polynomials.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jean Marie.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible.

Consider the quadratics

$$g(x)=x^2-5x+6$$$$f(x)=x^2-2x$$

In general, given desired roots $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$, the existence of $f,g$ depends on whether there exists distinct $i,j,k,l$ such that $r_i+r_j=r_k+r_l$.

Comment: That was what I could figure out. But we need a general proof for it. Can u plz help me with that.

Comment: This is a proof...

Comment: I think the OP means an heuristics to find this example or others maybe...

Comment: @donthousand there are infinite number of values for which the condition may hold can you please look up for that.

Comment: @JAOFELIX Not sure what you are asking. I think this is the point where you need to do the rest of the work yourself.

Comment: Ok then no offence @ don thousand I will keep you posted with the solution. Bye